# Memory leak in my React app because of firebase and how to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

The app I'm working on displays a user dashboard on login with a sidebar for navigation. It uses firebase. I do most of my data fetch from firebase in my `async componentDidMount()` and store the data in my component state. It takes a couple of seconds to finish all fetches. But if the user decides to navigate to another screen before the fetch is complete, I get the

> Can't call setState on unmounted component

warning (as expected). So I do some digging and find that

```
if(this.isMounted()) this.setState({updates:updates})
```

makes the warning go away, but then I also find that using `isMounted` is an antipattern.

The official documentation on this issue suggests tracking the mounted state ourselves by setting `_isMounted=true` in `componentDidMount` and then set it to false in the `componentWillUnmount`. The only way I see to achieve this would be through a variable in component state. Turns out, setState doesn't work in componentWillUnmount. **[Issue 1]** (I tried calling an external function from `componentWillUnmount` which in turn sets the state variable. Didn't work.)

The documentation suggests another way, to use cancellable promises. But I'm clueless about how to achieve that with `await firebase` calls. I also couldn't find any way to stop firebase calls mid-track. **[Issue 2]**

So now I'm stuck with the warning and data leaks.

a. How do I resolve this problem?
b. Is this something I need to take seriously?

Comment: You don't need to put `_isMounted` in your component state since it will not be used for rendering. You can put it directly on the component instance: `componentDidMount() { this._isMounted = true; } componentWillUnmount() { this._isMounted = false; }`

Comment: @Tholle Wow I really didn't know I could just keep variables like that!! I thought state was the only way to store data inside a component. Thank you so much. It works. Wish I had known this earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good practice to check if the component is still mounted when a request completes, if there is a risk of the component unmounting.

You don't need to put `_isMounted` in your component state since it will not be used for rendering. You can put it directly on the component instance instead.

**Example**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { data: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;

    fetch("/example")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
          this.setState({ data: res.data });
        }
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```